# iterator over display tag column in struts?

Tags: iterator, struts, displaytag

Hi friends i have developed an application of PhotoAlbum, in show photo jsp the page shows all user information along with their uploaded image names. the output it displays on jsp is similar to the below format.

```
==========================================================================  
| NAME    | FatherName |AGE|ADDRESS |   PhotoList                         |
==========================================================================
|nathjo r | FATHERNAME |12 | XYZ    |[asasdd, asada, asada, aasasada]     |
|SRT      | ERNAME     |12 | XYZ    |[1212, 1212, 1212]                   |
|SRY      | ERNAME     |12 | XYZ    |[bb, ccas, asdda, da, qwqda, qwqda, qwqda] |
==========================================================================
```

as you can see it is perfect, the last column[PhotoList] is a list of strings. so my question is i  want to do iteration [put logical iterator tag] on the last column to do additional operation depending on the number of element present in the last column along with displaying image names. **so what i thought is like this i know it is wrong any suggestion to do it like that.**

```
<display:table id="data" name="sessionScope.UserForm.userList" requestURI="/userAction.do" pagesize="3" >
        <display:column property="name" title="NAME" sortable="true"   />
        <display:column property="fatherName" title="User Name" sortable="true"  />
        <display:column property="age" title="AGE" sortable="true"   />
        <display:column property="address" title="ADDRESS" sortable="true"  />
        <logic:iterate property="photolist" id="photoId" indexId="index">
            ***here i want to display the image name***
        </logic:iterate>
</display:table>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Lets have iterate tag inside the `<display:column>` tag something like this

```
<display:table id="data" name="sessionScope.UserForm.userList" requestURI="/userAction.do" pagesize="3" >
        <display:column property="name" title="NAME" sortable="true"   />
        <display:column property="fatherName" title="User Name" sortable="true"  />
        <display:column property="age" title="AGE" sortable="true"   />
        <display:column property="address" title="ADDRESS" sortable="true"  />
        <display:column title="Photo List">
            <logic:iterate property="photolist" id="photoId" indexId="index">
                <s:property />,
            </logic:iterate>
        </display:column>
</display:table>
```